What steps should I take while doing surface intergal
$$\iint{\overrightarrow{F}\cdot\overrightarrow{n}dS}$$
where $\overrightarrow{F} = xy^2\overrightarrow{i}+yz^2\overrightarrow{j}+zx^2\overrightarrow{k}$ and S is the boundary surface of the region lying above the cone $z = \sqrt{\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{3}}$ and below the upper half of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4. \overrightarrow{n} $ is the outward-pointing normal.
All I know is to use divergence theorem to solve this question.
$div\overrightarrow{F} = y^2 + z^2 + x^2$
And I don't know what to do next.
By the cone equation and the sphere equation, I can get $1\le{z}\le{2}$ ; $0\le{x}\le{\sqrt{3}}$ ; $0\le{y}\le{\sqrt{3}}$
I should evaluate the surface integral by
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int \limits_{1}^{2}  y^2 + z^2 + x^2 dzdxdy = 13?$$
Or try the polar coordinate substitution
But the next problem is what is the limit of z
Same as above? $1\le{z}\le{2}$ or $\sqrt{4-r^2}\le{z}\le{\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{3}}}$
And the limits of r and $\theta$ are $0\le{r}\le{\sqrt{3}}$,$0\le{\theta}\le{2\pi}$
$$\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int \limits_{1}^{2}  r^2 + z^2 + dzdrd\theta = 9\pi?$$
The answer looks good.
However, it seems that I can also use spherical coordinate substitution.
Or actually my approach is completely wrong?
I am quite confused about surface integral.
What exactly I need to do while facing these questions?

Welcome to M.SE! I think fundamentally, you don't have an understanding of what the bounds of a multiple integral are supposed to represent. They do not represent intervals from a point to a point. For example when you are integrating over a volume as you do with triple integrals, the innermost bounds go from a surface to a surface (which means it can be a function of the remaining unintegrated variables). Once you do that integral, the volume collapses into a 2d projection, and then your next bounds would be a curve to a curve. The last bounds would finally be a point to a point

Your first attempt in Cartesian does not return the requested volume. What you have is that the innermost integral goes from the plane $z=1$ (not a point) to the plane $z=2$. Next, the cube "collapses" onto its shadow on the $xy$ plane if you viewed it from above. The next bound goes from the line $x=0$ in the $xy$ plane to the line $x=\sqrt{3}$. Finally the $y$ bounds go from the min to the max $y$ present in the shape. But you can see that the $z$ bounds really would need to go from the surface $z=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{3}}$ to the surface $z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and so on.

@Ninad Thanks for your reply. I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean the correct integral is
$$
\int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int \limits_{\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{3}}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} x^2+y^2+z^2 dzdxdy
$$?

The innermost integral must have a limit in other variables?
And the middle integral is
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} dx$$
?

That last comment is confusing. The one before looks right. For the calculation use cylindrical coordinates. It also helps to draw a picture in the $(\rho,z)$-plane of the region of integration.
